# Run CherryPy app on GAE and local server - need some tips on how to start

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, server, cherrypy

I have an app that I'm writing, currently hosted on GAE (and what I've gotten completed so far is working fine).  I want to also be able to have that app run on a local server, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

The goal being to be able to host this in the Google Cloud or on any other server I have access to (local, AWS, etc.) using the CherryPy server. Since the GAE install requires a little something like this:

`app = cherrypy.tree.mount(Main(), '/', config=conf)
run_wsgi_app(app)`

but running a local one requires something like this:

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(Main(), '/', config=conf)`

I find myself at a loss as to how to proceed.  Should there be an if catch to decide how to start the server?  If so, what should that trigger on?  Is there a way to just say "start this sucker up" that will be recognized by AppEngine and also by CherryPy running on a local server?

Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: why not have separate module for running local app? or probably you can recognize that it's a Google Cloud examining env vars. 
other option is always run it via WSGI: uwsgi/gunicorn for local runs.

Comment: Not sure how to pull that off.  I did find an interesting option in http://www.appscale.com/ though.  Seems promising.  Anyone have any experience with that which could be shared?

Comment: AFAIK GAE runs WSGI apps, so one of wsgi runners would fit fine, you don't really need something large for that.